# Unique constraint for a has_and_belongs_to_many constraint at the rails level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an index to ensure uniqueness for a has_and_belongs_to_many at the database level. How do I do the same at the rails level?

Comment: You could post some code and examples, your question is very vague at the moment. Anyway, have you tried it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with the "scope" param. Didn't do the trick.